# PS1 can't have two "\$"?

Tags: bash, ps1

I want my bash Prompt String 1 to have both the date/time and the return code of the last command. So, I thought I could just do

```
PS1="\[\e[00;34;01m\]\$(date +'%a %b %e, %T')\[\e[35m\] \$?\[\e[00m\] >> "
```

Which I thought would give me a blue date (like `Thu Jul 2, 01:01:01`) a purple return code and then just `>>` (given that the ansi escape sequences produce "normal" colors based on most pallets for terminals). However, it doesn't work.

---

```
PS1="\$? >> "
```

and

```
PS1="\$(date +\"%a %b %e, %T\") >> "
```

both work, though, and when I do it the first way, only the first `"\$"` gets interpreted and the other only gets interpreted when my bashrc is sourced. (So, the `"\$?"` gets evaluated to `0` initially and stays `0`.)

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Note: I have even tried `PS1='$(date +"%a %b %e, %T") $? >> '`

> Can anyone else replicate this in Unix bash? If so/if not, please leave a comment.

Comment: It could be simpler with `zsh`, and that's part of the reasons why my interactive shell is `zsh`

Comment: Are you having it create a `date` process for every single command you enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why bash ignores the second \$, but try using the **\D** format for the date:

```
PS1="\[\e[00;34;01m\]\D{%a %b %e, %T}\[\e[35m\] \$?\[\e[00m\] >> "
```

This works for me under bash version 4.2.46

Comment: I see; so bash interprets the prompt string `\D` as the date command without returning an exit code?

Comment: @dylnmc yes, have a look at the bash man page under "prompting"

Answer (score 3):

It isn't ignoring the `$?` (`\$?` is just an escaped version of `$?` so it isn't evaluated when you set the variable, but rather when the prompt string is expanded).

Instead, it's returning the exit code of the last command you ran; which in this case, is always the `$(date ...)` command from earlier in the prompt. Since that `date` command never fails, the return code is always 0.

To work around this, as Ian points out, you can use `\D{%a %b %e, %T}` instead of `\$(date ...)` in your prompt string to format the date; since that's built in and not a separate command, it won't clobber `$?`.

Comment: ah! I see; so I could just print the date command after like `\n\n\$? >>\[\e[A\]\$(date +'%a %b %e, %t')\n`... thanks

Comment: aw shucks... that's a problem because then the prompt would start at the beginning of the line... Ah; I think I will go with `\D`

Answer (score 1):

The `$?` that you see in the prompt is the exit code of date command. You can verify it as this:

```
$ PS1="\[\e[00;34;01m\]\$(exit 10)\[\e[35m\] \$?\[\e[00m\] >> "
10 >>
```

Work-around:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='EXIT_CODE=$?'
$ PS1="\[\e[00;34;01m\]\$(date +'%a %b %e, %T')\[\e[35m\] \$EXIT_CODE\[\e[00m\] >> "
```

Comment: I don't particularly like using the exit code. This is a very good solution, though. Thank you.